# keyof on a nullable subtype, "not assignable to parameter of type 'never'"

Tags: typescript

I have a type, `jsonReplyObject`.

```
export type jsonReplyObject = {
  commands?: {
    'relogin'?: boolean
    'throttled'?: boolean
  },
  success?: boolean,
  message?: string,
};
```

And a function declaration like this

```
function foo(command: keyof jsonReplyObject['commands']) {}
```

When I try to call `foo('relogin')`, I get `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`

If I change the declaration of `commands` above from `commands?:` to `commands:`, it solves this error and `keyof jsonReplyObject['commands']` works as I'd expect, enforcing that that argument is a possible key of `commands`. Unfortunately, it causes several other errors where instances of `jsonReplyObject` now require `commands` be provided.

What's the simplest way to fix this?

**I've removed a lot of commands to keep this brief, but several commands are not of boolean type. They're of types relevant to their purpose.**

Comment: You need to use the utility type NonNullable to exclude null and undefined before you use keyof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) utility type excludes `null` and `undefined`, so you can use `keyof` on that:

```
function foo(command: keyof NonNullable<jsonReplyObject['commands']>) {}
```

Previously, it gave you `never` because `keyof undefined` is `never`.

Another solution would be to use the built-in [`Required`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) type:

```
function foo(command: keyof Required<jsonReplyObject>['commands']) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `NonNullable` type :

```
function foo(command: keyof NonNullable<jsonReplyObject['commands']>) {}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBWBnCA7ASsMAG0QHkAjNYAY3gF44BvAKDjiogFsOBDbAEwwB%20AFyMWrOAHIowQhADmAS2ySRcMhAiFgvca0kwAFlAgwY2vqtEatO7OIC%20AGnEYArlSrAMQ65u28Lqwc3hjc8sBqGDBQyvIuDgDcTEwAZm7YNIo4cKmaABTsXLx8ogDWwIgQqXAAcji1boSE3GTaADyYOPhEpBTUMADakkU8-BiSALoAfACUjA4peRD50rIKypKzQA)